# How to change this for loop into while loop?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have this code that when u pass in aList = [5,8,2,13,1,8,3,1,8]
it prints countList= [0,  2,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]. Basically, say index 1 in countList is 2 because there are two number 1's in aList.

This is the code in for loop:

```
countList = 20*[0]

aList = [5,8,2,13,1,8,3,1,8]
for num in aList:
    countList[num] += 1
```

And I tried changing it to a while loop but prints countList= [0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  instead.

This is what I tried:

```
countList = 20*[0]

aList = [5,8,2,13,1,8,3,1,8]
index=0#initialize index

while index<len(aList):
    number=aList[index]
    count=0
    while count<number:
        countList[number] += 1
        count+=1
    index+=1
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you need the `while count<number` part?

Comment: I do not understand.
Why do you want to switch `for` with `while`?
and what is the real problem you are trying to solve, the use of `while` is rarely the idiomatic solution in python.

Comment: I'm planning to convert this to mips assembly language so I figured while loop will be easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many whiles. One for loop can be replaced with one while loop.

The inner while is not needed. Replace it with just an increment to the counter in the list.
You only need to track 3 things for a successful loop, the index which goes over the elements, it's initialization and the end condition.
They are in different places in the different looping commands but they are logically the same.

```
countList = 20*[0]

aList = [5,8,2,13,1,8,3,1,8]
index=0#initialize index

while index<len(aList):
    countList[aList[index]] += 1
    index+=1
```